# What is password for command "safaridriver --enable"

Tags: python, selenium, safari

What is the password for the command "safaridriver --enable"?

I tried to do the command "safaridriver --enable" in the terminal my MAC asks me the password. I put the password for sudo command but it doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If youre using Safari 10 the command "safaridriver --enable" wont work, there is no known workaround, you could upgrade a higher version. Using "safaridriver --enable" should work there.